# I want redirect http to https two categories (shop and university), other i want redirect to http

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

this don't work true, i get many redirects from shop and university

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(shop/.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /shop/
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(university/.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /university/


</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(shop/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(university/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

How do I make the right redirects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(shop|university)(/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^(shop|university)(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you, and if I had set the rules for the shop / university with a redirect to https now removed them, but redirect was, how often the server is restarted?

Comment: You need to clear th browser cache or try with other

Comment: after installation of the rules to all http transfers me on https but from universiti and shop puts on the main page. what could it be?

Comment: This is the opposite of what you want? Do you use a particular version of SSL ?

Comment: sorry, all works, but when i go to shop or university, i get errors:
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/shop/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.example.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.4'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: You need to change your link in the page. Use relative to the root:`/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.4%27` or without protocol. `//www.example.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.4%27`