# Mixed Content: The page at / SSL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

You can specify a redirect to https only two pages of the shop / university, but that does not redirect style css / js files.
This code works, but at the same time get a lot of errors:

```html
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/shop/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://www.example.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.4'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

If you comment out the last line, the https styles normal, but on the other pages there is no redirect to http

```html
#RewriteRule !^(shop|university)(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

this code in .htaccess

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(shop|university)(/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^(shop|university)(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: You have not accepted my solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34223844/i-want-redirect-http-to-https-two-categories-shop-and-university-other-i-want but you already use it :-(

Answer (score 1):

As I explained to you in your other question:

In your pages, you must use links relative to the root:

```
/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css
```

Or without protocol:

```
//www.example.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css
```

But never use `http:` in `https` pages